# large float array constants in separate class

Tags: objective-c

The following array x is not large, but it is my example array.

```
float x[4] = {1.0f, 2.0f, 4.0f, 8.0f};
```

Say, I want to use the array in my ViewController `BSViewController.h/.m` . I have included `BSParam.h` in `BSViewController.h`, but I don't know what else to do to use `x` in `BSViewController.m`

Below is the code so far for my class which will containt my constant arrays.

```
//
//  BSParam.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface BSParam : NSObject

@end



//
//  BSParam.m

#import "BSParam.h"

@implementation BSParam

#include <stdio.h>


float x[4] = {1.0f, 2.0f, 4.0f, 8.0f};

@end
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) If you want to make it available outside of your class, use the `extern` keyword to make it available:

```
//  BSParam.h
extern float x[4];


//  BSParam.m
#import "BSParam.h"    
float x[4] = { 1.0f, 2.0f, 4.0f, 8.0f };

// BSViewController.m
#import "BSParam.h"

- (void)dummy {
  float t = x[0]; // etc.
}
```

2) Anyhow, this solution will make the variable `x` global, and available anywhere in your application, without any context/namespace to access it, so that's not the optimal solution.

To make global values accessible to other parts of your application, you better use the **Singleton pattern**, or use a class method for that.

For example:

```
@interface BSParam : NSObject
+(float[4])x;
@end

@implementation BSParam
+(float[4])x {
    return (float[4]){ 1.0f, 2.0f, 4.0f, 8.0f };
}
@end
```

So that you can use `[BSParam x]` to access your array, instead of just `x`, adding some *namespace* to access this `x` array, avoiding the risk to mess with other local variables or whatever.

Comment: I am trying to use your Singleton pattern approach. But when I say `l= [BSParam x];` I get the error message "Use of undefined identifier 'l'". How do I fix that? Adding `NSArray *` does not help.

Comment: ??! Why are you talking about `NSArray` whereas you wanted to use plain C arrays on the first time? `[BSParam x]` returns `float[4]` so why don't you use that type of variable?! `float* l = [BSParam x]` or `float l = [BSParam x][0]`. (Or if you want to use `NSArray` to make it more simple tu use, use `NSArray` all the way, but be coherent!)

Answer (score 1):

You can make functions to return them for you, or just use `extern` declarations in the header:

```
extern float x[4];
```